# Browserify/Webpack bundled 3rd party core node module (npm module) is not working in React Native 0.59, only working in debug mode

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, browserify, v8

I am trying to use browserified / webpack bundled file bundled.js in react native,

It works in development/debug mode due to chrome's V8 engine.

But fails to work when .apk or .ipa file is created from react-native due to JSCore engine compiler internally used by React Native.

version- React-native 0.59

How can we run a core node module in React Native ?

NOTE: We are having our own custom npm module (business logic) which we are using in Nodejs and Angular in the browser. We want to reuse that module for react-native also...

Comment: there are react-native compatible modules

Comment: Hi, we are having our own custom npm module (business logic) which we are using in Nodejs and Angular in browser. We want to reuse that module for react-native also

Comment: Can you tell the exact error thrown by JSCore?

Comment: Hi, as per my knowledge JSCore engine will only come into play after building .apk and.ipa file... So my browserfied/webpack bundle.js file has many require() statements in that file which is not getting resolved.

But it does work in debug/development mode since react-native uses V8 engine.
Here is some more info on similar lines.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1871